# Network Policy not enforced on Minikube Calico cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, calico

I have a minikube cluster installed and I am trying to get a simple NetworkPolicy working.
I have installed Calico CNI in my minikube cluster.

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE

kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-7bdbfc669-jz9m2                           1/1     Running   0             40m
kube-system   calico-node-ncwp5                                                 1/1     Running   0             40m
```

Here is my NetworkPolicy.
All the pods are in the same namespace.

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: db-access-control
  namespace: bootapp
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql8
  ingress:
    - from:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: product-service
```

```
$ kubectl get po -n bootapp

NAME                                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE     LABELS
inventory-service-7d7c8dc79-b9hcs                                 1/1     Running   0             2m16s   app=inventory-service,pod-template-hash=7d7c8dc79
mysql8-6b858fb5dc-9lj9p                                           1/1     Running   0             2m17s   app=mysql8,pod-template-hash=6b858fb5dc
product-service-5dcccc579c-9fm2t                                  1/1     Running   0             2m12s   app=product-service,pod-template-hash=5dcccc579c
```

I was expecting 'inventory-service' to be NOT READY, as it should not be able to connect to the DB on statup.

Both 'inventory-service' and 'product-service' are spring boot (data-jpa) apps trying to connect to mysql db on startup.

Do I need to configure anything to enable network policy evaluation by Calico on my Minikube cluster ?

How do I debug if calico is even trying to enforce the NetworkPolicy or not ?

**UPDATE :**
Moving to Cilium as CNI plug-in seems to be working fine.

```
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/network-policy-provider/cilium-network-policy/
```